# How to authenticate inside an iframe when it is blocked by X-Frame-Options

Tags: authentication, iframe, oauth-2.0

I am working with an application where another application is embedded inside an iframe.

The embedded application uses a google service which requires authentication.

Of course Google is not happy about this

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/error?authError=[...characters...].apps.googleusercontent.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'
```

Is there any alternative for authenticating and connecting to this service within the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If `X-Frame-Options` is set to `DENY` then supporting browsers will [refuse to display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) the site in an iframe regardless of site settings or domain.

This behavior is intended to prevent [clickjacking](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html) attacks.

If you have control over the browser your users are utilizing, you can select a browser that does not support `X-Frame-Options`.